# Google Anthos - Cluster Backup

Tags: google-anthos

Does anyone tried to backup google anthos cluster via bmctl command here?

I'm try to backup my current cluster and planning to restore it to another cluster into a new location. But I'm having errors while backing up.. Please see screenshot.

ERROR: `Error: failed to backup node config files: ssh: subsystem request failed`

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you..

- MD

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and [help/on-topic] - this question doesn't look programming-related to me.

Comment: Sorry @OlafKock

Already solved my issue too.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
[backup/confirm] Are you sure you want to proceed with the backup? [y/N]: y
[2022-07-13 10:40:58+0800] Take etcd snapshot on pod etcd-anthos01
[2022-07-13 10:40:58+0800] Take etcd snapshot on pod etcd-anthos02
[2022-07-13 10:40:59+0800] Take etcd snapshot on pod etcd-anthos03
[2022-07-13 10:41:00+0800] Backup files on machine 192.168.99.151
Error: failed to backup node config files: ssh: subsystem request failed
```

I'm sorry but since I'm just new in Anthos, looks like the error message above can be ignore.. I found the backup files within same directory of the kubeconfig and cluster config files.

My bad.. And thank you.